# If I enlarge a streaming web video, it looks pixellated. When I fullscreen, it looks smooth. How can I force this smoothing filter always?

Tags: video, streaming, fullscreen, anti-aliasing

I want the same smoothing filter to be applied even when I don't fullscreen, at any scale. Windows 7 64bit, nvidia geforce 9500 GT. Firefox browser.

Comment: Please provide the URL for a video that behaves this way - right now I don't know if you're talking YouTube, hulu, flash, Netflix, or any one of dozens of other formats...

Comment: I can't provide a working link as it's a paid stream and they don't seem to do free ones. I did however just find the source of the script that embeds their video player, and one of the parameters is scale=noscale. I was forcing enlargement by changing the width and height parameters and by using firefox's zoom. Can I somehow change that noscale parameter locally? swfobject.embedSWF('http://custlogin.audiovideoweb.com/cl/assets/mo/mo.swf', 
  eid, 
  '867', 
  '557', 
[snip]
  {
    allowFullScreen: 'true',
    scale: 'noscale'});

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the video size. If the video size is HD Big resolution size then the video should look quite good when fullscreen. But if the video size is small, when you make the video fullscreen, it will look all blurry and pixelated. I doubt there is any "Smoothing filter" unless the video is a big size, high quality video. I don't know if I'm right or wrong with this, but I noticed it as well when I watch youtube videos or just regular videos on my computer.